# express-validator and populating an input field after an error

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm relatively new to node and express, and have come across a problem I can't seem to solve.

I've created a SSCCE which tries to take two inputs, name and height, and if there's a validation error render the same page again with those values.

If I enter '2.2.2' into the height field (obviously not a float), the value is not re-rendered. If I change the height input to type="text", the field is rendered with the previous value. All other fields of type text behave as expected.

I've put 'novalidate' on the form, but is this a quirk with the number input type? Or have I made a simple mistake?

(I'm also slightly confused as to why 'isFloat()' accepts '2' as valid)

Any help would be appreciated

app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('test', {
        pageTitle: 'Test',
        hasError: false,
        validationErrors: []
    })
});

app.post('/', 
    [
        check('name', 'Name must be at least 2 letters in length')
            .isLength({min: 3}),
        check('height', 'Height must be a float')
            .isFloat()
    ] , 
    (req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            console.log(errors.array());
            return res.render('test', {
                pageTitle: 'Error',
                hasError: true,
                validationErrors: errors.array(),
                person: {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    height: req.body.height
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.send(`Person created: ${req.body.name}, height: ${req.body.height}`);
        }
    });

app.listen(3000);
```

test.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><%= pageTitle %></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="errorMessage"><%= validationErrors.length > 0 ? validationErrors[0].msg:'' %></div>
    <form action="/" class="test-form" method="POST" novalidate>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<%= hasError ? person.name:'' %>">

        <label for="height">Height</label>
        <input type="number" name="height" id="height" value="<%= hasError ? person.height:'' %>">    
        <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this. There didn't seem to be any way to get an input field of type number to submit an invalid value, even with novalidate.

So I just changed the type to text.